# Confluence - Looking for user experiences running AntiVirus to Scan Attachments

Tags: anti-virus, confluence

We're exploring confluence server configurations and want to use AV software to scan attachments.

I'm looking for advice/experience in setting up AV software for that purpose.

Example questions I have....

- What is your confluence setup? single server, cluster, specs of
  server?
- What are you scanning?
- Location of the data you're scanning, network, local?
- How frequently are you scanning?
- Are you running the AV application locally on the confluence server?
- Are you experiencing performance issues?
- Any tuning tips? etc.

This question is also posted on Atlassian's [Answers Site](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/31631/looking-for-user-experiences-running-antivirus-to-scan-attachments)

Answer (score 1):

I don't bother when running an internal wiki or when using a Linux box. I should probably use clamav on the upload folder...

If I were running a publicly available instance on a Windows box I would set it up just like any other web server. For the attachment folder set up the scans on write and a rare (weekly, monthly, etc) full scan and do a scan on each write.

Comment: I would advise you also run an AV scan for an internal wiki or Linux server, as your clients could be running Windows and becoming infected.  The real question is what happens to Confluence if the AV software were to Quarantine an attachment.

Comment: I suggest integrating properly using the Confluence API. Just deleting the files is not enough. What about user feedback? You also need to ensure that the attachment data in Confluence knows about your deletion. In [attachmentAV](https://attachmentav.com/), we add labels to clean attachments and we delete/archive infected ones with a comment to notify the uploader. You should be able to build something similar for Server.